# Bash invoke a function repeatedly

Tags: bash, input, while-loop, user-input, repeat

Im using **bash version 3.2.57(1)**-release (x86_64-apple-darwin14)

How can I repeatedly invoke a function until the user decides to quit?

The function gets invoked if I place it at the top, inside the while loop, but it would execute repeatedly.

```
    call_func () {
            echo "Im inside call_func"
            echo "some text: " >> file.txt

    }

    while true
    do
            echo "1) call_func "
            echo "q) to quit"
            echo "\n"
            echo "Enter your selection \c"
            read answer

            case "$asnwer" in
                    q|Q) exit;;
            call_func 
    esac
    done
```

Comment: Should be `case "$answer" in`

Comment: Recommended reading: `help break`.

Comment: yes, I've amended it

Answer (score 0):

My previous answer covers how to fix your existing code, here I'm going to recommend a better way to do it (given that you're using `bash` specifically):

```bash
select answer in call_func quit; do
    case $answer in
        (call_func) call_func;;
        (quit) break;;
        ("") echo "Unknown option. Press return again to see available options.";;
    esac
done
```

Example session with the above script:

```
1) call_func
2) quit
> 1
Im inside call_func
> 6
Unknown option. Press return again to see available options.
> 
1) call_func
2) quit
> 2
```

The `select` keyword in bash will automatically set up a numbered menu for you, and loop receiving input. It will also translate the number the user gave into the text provided for that number (`call_func` or `quit` in this case).

`select` is documented in the bash man pages, but essentially it's formed of three parts:

```bash
select VARIABLENAME in LIST OF ITEMS
do
    CODE
done
```

Where `VARIABLENAME` is the variable to be set when the user makes a choice, `LIST OF ITEMS` is a list of choices to display, and `CODE` is the code to execute when the user makes a choice. The `select` construct is a loop, so it will keep executing until you `break`.

Comment: The function gets invoked the first time only, when the function completes and the user selects the function again, it does not get invoked again. My actual function is invoking another function. Does this have something to do with it?

Comment: If you're having trouble calling the function more than once, is it possible you can show the code for that function (edit into the question)? I think the problem may lie within the function.

Answer (score -1):

> The function gets invoked if I place it at the top, inside the while loop, but it would execute repeatedly.

Yep. You did this right, the function should indeed be above (outside) the `case` statement. Your issue is this:

```sh
    call_func
    case "asnwer" in
        q|Q) exit;;
    esac
```

This *would* be correct, but you're using the string `asnwer` in the case block. You meant to use the variable:

```sh
    call_func
    case $answer in
        q|Q) exit;;
    esac
```

With this change made, you should properly be able to exit from the loop by typing "q".

Comment: Can someone explain why the downvote was given to this answer? I believe it solves the problem the question poses, in the way the question's author expects. If that's not the case please make that clear to me.